# how to compress and decompress xml present in URL C++

Tags: c++, xml, saml

I writing the saml SP in C++ but don't know how to compress the xml.

> http://acme.com:16006/idp/samlv20?SAMLRequest={xmlCompressedandBase64encodedString}

Now `xmlCompressedandBase64encodedString` is the problematic part I know Base64 encoding but xml compression I am not aware off.

My saml request will be looking like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <samlp:AuthnRequest 
        xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
        xmlns:enc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" 
        xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" 
        xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" 
        xmlns:x500="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:profiles:attribute:X500" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" 
        ID="id-_Abcd1234&-rQjG" 
        Version="2.0" 
        IssueInstant="2018-05-03T06:02:22Z" 
        Destination="http://acme.com:16006/idp/samlv20">
    <saml:Issuer Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity">
            https://flight.com::14213/sp
    </saml:Issuer>
    <samlp:NameIDPolicy AllowCreate="true"/>

    </samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

Same goes for decompression of SamlRespone.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML_2.0) indicating that you should use DEFLATE altorithm.

[zlib](https://zlib.net/) is one of the most famous library that implements DEFLATE algorihm. I heard Boost.iostream can also do that using zlib as dependency, but I am not sure.